# dart wait for inner Future

Tags: mysql, dart

I'm trying to execute some queries which have a reference as foreign keys on each other, so I have to wait until the outer future is finished.
This algorithm is placed inside a function which returns a future.

```
Future<List<int>> newEntry(Session session) {
    bool success = true;
    List<int> error = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8(
    "ERROR 3623231 (Experiencebox could not be saved )", session: session);
    Future coucheFutureQuerySave = new Future(() {
      new Couchbase().couchConnExperiencebox.set(uniqueId, UTF8.encode(
          documentOriented.toString())).catchError((error) {
        print("COUCHEBASE ERROR 338420: " + error.toString());
        success = false;
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("COUCHEBASE ERROR 338121: " + error.toString());
      success = false;
    });
    // Save data to MySql Database
    //create archiv entry
    Future <Results> mysql = mysqlCon.query(
        getQuery()).catchError((error) {
      print("failed archive");
      success = false;
    }).whenComplete((){
      print("completed archive");
      //querystring for insert word
      String wordQuery = new Tag().getInsertWordIfNotExists(tags);
      mysqlCon.query( wordQuery ).catchError((error) {
        print("failed word");
        success = false;
      }).whenComplete((){
        print("completed word");
        //query string for insert tags in blog
        String tagQuery = new Tag().getInsertTagsInBlogIfNotExists(tags, uniqueId);
        mysqlCon.query( tagQuery ).catchError((error) {
          print("failed tag in blog");
          success = false;
        });
      });
    });
    return Future.wait([mysql, coucheFutureQuerySave]).then((e) {
      // Save data to CoucheBase
      if (success) {
        print("completed all");
        return Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('OK', session: session, data:
            [new JsonObject.fromJsonString('{"id":"' + uniqueId + '"}')]);
      } else {
        print("failed");
        success = false;
      }
    });
}
```

when running it i got this out:

> === TO CLIENT ===
>   completed archive
>   completed all
>   === TO CLIENT ===
>   failed word
>   completed word
>   completed tag in blog
>   completed voting

So my question is, how can I wait for Future `mysql` until it has completed its "childs" (in `whenCompleted()` function). I also tried with `then()` instead of `whenCompleted()` but this doesn't make any differences.

Comment: It's not possible to tell for many calls in your code whether they are async or sync, there fore it's hard to tell what's the cause. If you would create a minimal example which allows to reproduce the problem it would be much easier to point to the problem.

Comment: You normally continue with `then`. `whenCompleted` is like `finally` in a try/catch block. It's also called when your async execution produces an async error, `then` is only called when the async execution returns normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you always return the future when you call async functions within async functions to keep them connected. 
When you call an async function like

```dart
.then((x) => someAsync())
```

the future returned from `someAsync()` is automatically returned but when your code has a block body like

```dart
.then((x) {
  return someAsync()
 })
```

you need to return explicitly.

There are two lines which start with

```dart
mysqlCon.query(
```

which should actually be

```dart
return mysqlCon.query(
```

This line

```dart
new Couchbase()
```

should probably be

```dart
return new Couchbase()
```

Using the new async/await feature can simplify your code notably.

Comment: thank you very much, adding the return statement to it works perfectly. `return new Couchbase()` is not necessary, because it is independent and I'm waiting for it in Future.wait(...)

Comment: If you don't add the `return` before `new Couchbase()` the future finishes **immediately** not after `...set(...` has finished. Only omit `return` if you really don't care about when the execution is finished.